# Touch icon Windows 7 mobile

Tags: windows, mobile, icons, touch

Is there some sort of  for Windows 7 (7.5) mobile?

When users add a website to the homescreen now all they see is a screenshot. I wonder if there's some kind of method to force an icon. Quick Google search didn't help me.

Comment: Ah I just voted the feature up on Microsofts to-do list: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-app-platform/suggestions/1899765-customize-pinned-tiles-for-html5-applications

Comment: Windows Phone 7 (7.5) is outdated. For example [HTML5MobileBoilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/mobile-boilerplate) project do not support it.